# Click-Once Alternative Icon Locations

Tags: .net, clickonce, desktop, icons, shortcut

Is there any features inside click-once to push multiple shortcuts?  (Such as to desktop, Startup Menu, etc)  In the past I've always done that as part of the form load event of my deployed application (installation triggers the application to launch--thus I can use form load to complete the setup process).  I'm wondering however if that's the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create arbitrary shortcuts with ClickOnce. The only additional option you have is "Create desktop shortcut" in the Publish -> Options dialog under Manifests.

As with having the application create shortcuts during runtime: I would not do this since you are making changes to the system that is not picked up as part of the installation package. Thus, when uninstalling the application you will probably leave orphaned files.